# shared_ptr error expression must have arithmetic, enum, pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm trying to check if a shared_ptr didn't call shared_ptr.reset()

I have a

```
std::shared_ptr<Shape> m_shape;
```

and I'm trying to do

```
 if(m_shape.reset()==false)
 {
    dothis();
 }
```

i want to check and see if m_shape is active and being used... and reset says when a shared_ptr stopped being used

but i keep getting an error on m_shape saying that expression must have arithmetic, enum, pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reset()` is a function that resets the shared_ptr, and returns `void`. It most certainly does not tell you if the `shared_ptr` is currently managing an object. In fact, calling it guarantees that it's no longer managing an object.

Instead, `shared_ptr` has a conversion to `bool` that tells you if it's currently managing an object. So you can just say

```
if (m_shape) {
    // m_shape has an object
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to check if the shared_ptr is being currently used